# How to not format emoji in slack?

Tags: slack

In a desperate attempt to reduce noise on slack, I am looking for a way to not format emoji into images.

E.G. I would like to see plain :+1: instead of the corresponding image with the "+1" or to see the plain :-) instead of the yellow smile.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

```
Settings -> messages & media -> Emoji style -> display emoji as plain text
```

Much better now!